# Go get is trying to fetch locally instead of from remote

Tags: git, go, gitlab

I am trying to pull down a private Gitlab repo for the first time, but `go get` seems to be trying to find the repo in my local `go/src/` directory instead of the URL I pass it:

```
➜  workspace go get gitlab.com/repo/db
package gitlab.com/repo/db: no Go files in /Users/MyName/go/src/gitlab.com/repo/db
```

I've confirmed my SSH access to Gitlab is working. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you enabled `GOPRIVATE` for private repo? Run before the execution of the go get command (export will add variable to shell for current session).

   ```
   export GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/repo/db"
   go get gitlab.com/repo/db
   ```
2. Another aproach I have found is to use expansion `...` while you doing `go get`

   ```
   go get -u gitlab.com/repo/db/...
   ```

   This can produce a verbose error messages or solve the issue.

Comment: I had enabled `GOPRIVATE`. The problem turned out to be in my `.gitconfig` `insteadOf`. See my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my `.gitconfig` file.

I needed to change

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

to

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```